# Use different DNS servers an different SSID's with DD-WRT router

Tags: dns, wireless-router, dd-wrt

I'm running a Buffalo AirStation running DD-WRT and have configured with a physical SSID, "ukAP" and a Virtual Interface "usAP". I'd like to setup connection from one SSID "ukap" to use the standard DNS servers from ISP and the "usAP" to use the DNS servers provided by unotelly/uno DNS.

The idea being if I want to appear as connected from the US and watch Hulu etc, I just switch SSID which is allot simpler for everyone in the house than manually configuring dns settings.

I'm thinking I'll need to setup a DNSintercept that I've seen noted in the [dd-wrt wiki](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/OpenDNS#Intercept_DNS_Port) but it doesn't talk about for a specific Virtual Interfaces. Anyone know the commands to do this?

Firmware: DD-WRT v24SP2-MULT

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this (saved to Administration -> Commands -> Save Firewall)

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i [interface 1] -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to [IP of first ISPs DNS]
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i [interface 2] -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to [IP of second ISPs DNS]
```

To get the correct interface names, telnet/ssh to the router and run *ifconfig*. The virtual interface is probably *wl0.1*, and the normal wireless could be *wl0, wlan0, vlan1* (If unsure, watch the RX/TX bytes in ifconfig while using the different SSIDs). For the IPs, just enter the first of a ISP's DNS servers.

Comment: Some providers give you 2 addresses. How do you put two address for one after another. Will this work `--to [xx.xx.xx.xx, xx.xx.xx.xx]`?

Answer (score 0):

DNS will have nothing to do with allowing you to appear to be from a certain physical place. In fact, Hulu will have no idea where you got your DNS answers.

DNS works like this:

```
1) User types domain into browser
2) Client looks in cache for IP address of domain, if not found,
   2b) Client asks DNS server for IP address of domain
3) Client receives IP address of domain from either cache or DNS
4) Client then uses IP address to contact Hulu
```

Using an American DNS server will do nothing but take more time for your clients to receive their DNS query answers. Hulu checks your physical IP address to determine where you are, which has nothing to do with DNS lookups. You will need to use an American *proxy* if you wish to fool Hulu, and there is no way to route a DD-WRT connection through a proxy based on which SSID the client is connected through.

Sorry, bro. :(

Comment: I appreciate how DNS works, check out how the  unotelly/uno DNS service works [link](http://www.unotelly.com/unodns/whatisunodns)

Comment: UnoDNS is offering "VPN" service, which is the same thing as a proxy. You will "tunnel" your connection to Hulu through their VPN, which will make it appear as though you are coming from America. :)

Comment: Yes, but in order to do that, you put in their DNS server and they only proxy request to certain sites like netflix by giving you back the ip of one of their proxy servers. For others their dns servers just returns the normal ip of the site. So it's necessary to use their dns for their service, which is what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: You are wrong. What I'm saying is that DNS is a discrete process. You can obtain those IPs completely separately from their DNS servers (you could even write them down and mail them with a stamped envelope) and Netflix would not (and could not) know how you got those IPs. It is NOT NECESSARY to get endpoint IPs via a service's DNS. As long as you use the right IPs, you can get them from anywhere.

Comment: What I was saying is that Unotelly's DNS doesn't return the "correct" ip for sites like Netflix, but returns the ip of one of Unotelly's proxy servers. So when your browser tries to go to Netflix to get the content, it actually goes to a proxy server that reroutes the connection. If you go to Facebook, Unotelly's DNS will act like a regular DNS, so your browser still goes to Facebook's servers to get the content. The advantage over a VPN is that you won't experience any slowdowns for your regular traffic, it only reroutes specific sites, and you can even pick the country to reroute through.